# Error when getting records from xlsx file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, xlsx

I am getting an error when I attempt to read the records from my xlsx file.
The error is **"Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only."**
I have verified that the file is not read-only.  Any ideas what could be causing the error?

My code is:

```
string strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtSourcePath.Text);
string strFilePath = txtSourcePath.Text;

string strDirectoryPath = strFilePath.Substring(0, (txtSourcePath.TextLength - (strFileName.Length + 1)));

string conn = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=DELIMITED""", strDirectoryPath);
OleDbConnection oleDBConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
oleDBConn.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [" + strFileName + "]", conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

When I hover over `ds` I don't see any records

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This 


for xls
     <add key="xlsConnection" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=##PATH##;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"/>


for xlsx
        <add key="xlsxConnection" value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=##PATH##;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;'"/>
```

Required to install : [microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 driver](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)

Replace Path of your excel file path